# Blazor project deployment issues when deploying in sub-folder

Tags: blazor

I created a Blazor server app.  Works fine locally.  But on the server,  it needs to be deployed such that `mydomain.com/mynewapp` invokes it.  Changed the base URL in `_hosts.cstml` file to `/mynewapp`.   CSS, etc. are loaded correctly from the sub-folder but even if I hardcoded `/_framework/blazor.server.js` to a fixed path,  it always tries to hit `mydomain.com/_framework/blazor.server.js`.  I can't find this file anywhere either in the dev environment or in deployment but if I deploy the project in the root,  it works fine.

I am sure I am missing something.  Any pointers?  Have already spent hours trying to figure it out.